# NW JS - Download and Save a File from URL

Tags: jquery, node.js, node-webkit

I recently started developing Desktop Apps using NW.JS and I need to download a file from a URL (http://someurl.org/file.zip) and I manage to save the file but it seems corrupted or malformed and I can't open the zip or unzip it.

I'm using jQuery to download the file and the 'fs' module from Node.JS to save it.

Here is the ajax request:

```
module.exports.download = function (jQuery, url) {

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url         : url,
        timeout     : 1000000
    });

};
```

Here is the rest:

```
$('#btnUpdateClient')
            .click(function () {
                ClientDownload
                    .download($, addresses.CLIENT_URL)
                    .complete(function (xhr, status) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        fs.writeFile('./files/staClient.zip', xhr.responseText, function (err) {

                            if(err) {
                                alert('error!');
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                alert('file Saved!');
                            }

                        });
                    });
            });
```

Something is clearly missing, AND the .zip file is 3.8 MB but when I fs.writeFile() the file ends up being 7.3 MB

I'm fairly new to NW.JS, any advice?

Answer (score 3):

If the progress of download is important for you, Use this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var req = http.get('http://someurl.org/file.zip', function (res) {

    var fileSize = res.headers['content-length'];
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    var a = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        a += chunk;
        document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = Math.round(100*a.length/fileSize) + "";
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        fs.writeFile('D:\\file.zip', a, 'binary', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('finished');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a note for anyone having "memory leak" problems with files larger than 260mb, the `a += chunk` method is responsible for this, the best fix to prevent memory leak (and eventual app crash) is to calculate the opposite, start with `a = filesize` instead of `a = ""`, decrease with `a -= chunk.length` and change the progress calculation to the respective inverse method `Math.round((1-(a/fileSize))*100)`.

If I didn't make this change and used Sam's code as it was then my app always crashed, now it can download with success files as big as 1GB without significant memory impact.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I just realized I didn't even need to use jQuery, I simply used NodeJS like so:

```
$('#btnUpdateClient')
            .click(function () {

                var file = fs.createWriteStream('./files/staClient.zip');

                var request = http.get(addresses.CLIENT_URL, function (response) {
                    response.pipe(file);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

All these methods require you to write your own `Save as` dialog window. I would recommend to [call Chrome Extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#method-download) for file downloading

```js
chrome.downloads.download({url: 'https://ya.ru'});
```

[image]